# How to downgrade from Apache Hadoop 1.2.1 to 0.20.2 version

Tags: hadoop

I started my POC using **Apache Hadoop 1.2.1** on **Windows 7** using **Cygwin**.

Believe me it is full of bugs. Initially I tried to start fixing up bugs....incorporate patches as and where suggested.

But it is limit now, it gives failure error...permissions issues...just anytime now.

I want to know about the steps or probably easy way out to **downgrade to 0.20.2**

Comment: Running on Linux is not an option?

Comment: I'd recommend to download and install a Windows distro, like Hortonworks HDP http://hortonworks.com/hdp/downloads/ . Is tested on Windows, has and MSI installer, Ambari support, and contains Hadoop 2.6 now I believe.

Comment: You can use hadoop-2.6.0 which has windows support natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just repeat the installation  steps you followed for hadoop 1.2.* with hadoop 0.20 , ie download the zip , extract it , edit the config files and set local variables correctly .

You can also keep the old installation if you like ,but its better to keep the setup clean and simple with desired hadoop version.

One more alternative is , instead of Cygwin ,use preconfigured images of hadoop distribution , say [CDH 3.*](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_previous.html?bcsi_scan_c9e2df1c0800a1cc=JblbUchdjzTyX0hffUcP6Nd/0KsCAAAA5pEpCA==&bcsi_scan_filename=cdh_vd_cdh_package_previous.html) can be a good candidate for learning hadoop using virtual machine on a windows (u will need virtualbox or VMwares s/w for this)

Comment: yes , cloudera, hortonworks or any other distro can be chosen .

Comment: CDH is a Linux distro running on Cygwin. HDP for Windows is a native Windows distro. Something to consider.

Comment: I was recommending , CDH on virtual box or MapR may be. HDP is also good option .But we don't know whether he is learning hadoop development or administration so the choice is open for him.